# Display only validatorMessage when validation failed

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a register form with multiple input text all the fields are required and some fields has `validateRegex` and validator message like the input text of an email.

```
<h:form>
 <p:outputLabel  value="Login:" for="pseudo"/>    
 <p:inputText  id="pseudo" value="#{customerMB.login}" title="Pseudo" required="true" validatorMessage="Enter a valid email" requiredMessage="Please enter your email.">
                                            <f:validateRegex pattern="([^.@]+)(\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\.)+([^.@]+)" />
 </p:inputText>
 <p:watermark for="pseudo" value="Enter you email address" />  
</h:form>
```

I need to show only validator message and not the required message. I mean when I submit the form without filling the field the outputLabel is highlighted with red (that works fine ) but when I submit using a wrong form of email address it is not shown the validator message.
 If i use `<p:message for="pseudo">` it will show the required message too.

Comment: so you never want the required message to appear? only the red highlight?

Comment: @Damian yes but show the validator message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a project which has a email validation and here what I did:

```
 <p:inputText  id="pseudo" value="#{customerMB.login}"title="Pseudo" required="true"    validatorMessage="Enter a valid email" requiredMessage="">
     <f:validateRegexpattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
       <p:ajax event="blur" update="growl"/>
  </p:inputText>
```

It shows the validation message right after leaving the field.

Comment: so you basically posted the same answer I had already posted and added the ajax for blur event, which wasn't asked in the first place..

Comment: I use it in my java project.  My answer is different of yours. My regular expression is different and if you take a look at primefaces showcase you will see a similar answer. It's a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Put an empty string as validatorMessage, like this:

```
<p:inputText  id="pseudo" value="#{customerMB.login}" title="Pseudo" required="true" validatorMessage="Enter a valid email" requiredMessage="">
     <f:validateRegex pattern="([^.@]+)(\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\.)+([^.@]+)" />
</p:inputText>
```